# Disable Ray Tune parallel hyperparameter tuning

Tags: huggingface-transformers, hyperparameters, ray

I have an issue with running hyperparameter optimization on my language model because my setup requires about 20GB of GPU memory to train. Without working in a distributed fashion, I keep getting OutOfMemoryError when running ray tune for any trial worker that is not the first.

I figure this is because my Population Based Training runs trials in parallel and it is erroring out due to these out of memory issues.

As such, I figured I would tell Ray to run serially, and I believe I do this by  setting `tune.TuneConfig(max_concurrent_trials=1)`.

Does anyone know how to set this parameter in the HuggingFace transformers flow? On a high level, I execute hyperparameter optimization using `trainer.hyperparameter_search()`, but I do not see where I can set it to not run trials concurrently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass it as a kwarg, eg. trainer.hyperparameter_search(max_concurrent_trials=1).